Как отключить вывод пути и всего лишнего, нужен только результат в терминале VS CODE (Linux)?
Как отключить вывод пути и всего лишнего, нужен только результат в терминале VS CODE (Linux)?
ОС: Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL)


Выполни в терминале эти команды:
PS0="\[\033[2J\033[1;1H\]"
PS1=

будет чистый терминал.
Можно добавить в ~/.bash_profile
Переменная
PS1 отчищается для того, чтобы не отображал [user@host path]$ перед командой.
В PS0 помещаются две последовательности:

\033[2J - для отчистки терминала
\033[1;1H - для возвращения курсора в верхний левый угол

Такие "невидимые" последовательности в переменных PS надо обрамлять в \[ ... \], иначе будут проблемы с позиционированием.
Таким образом, PS0 выводится сразу после самой команды, перед выполнением самой команды.
PS1 - это приглашение (PROMPT) на ввод следующей команды.
Подробнее можно почитать:
Про управляющие последовательности https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html
Про переменные PSx  https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bash/Prompt_customization
